# Youtube api v3 - list of deleted vids

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

we are using the youtube api to keep track of youtube videos. currently we "watch" around 30k videos. now we have the issue that we want to figure out which videos have been deleted. is there some way to get e.g. a list of all deleted vids of a channel or some other way?
sending a single request (and handling 404) for each video doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Comment: Looking for deleted videos is only part of the issue. First, YouTube keeps a 'deleted' video around with status 'delete' for a few days, then it's wiped from the database. Check for both. Also, many times a video status can be set to rejected, moved to private, set to be not embeddable, etc. Many things to check for. You could try the Video Link Checker plugin as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can not do it with only youtube api.
You can create your own database of all your videos and channels and periodically sync it with youtube to check what video status changed or not exists in list anymore.

Youtube API has method [Videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#parameters), it returns list of all your videos.

Another tricky way: load every video url and check the size of content instead of parsing html.

If video exists then content size about 50kb, if not - 15kb. It seems youtube do not pass Content-Length header. That's why you need to load content to check size.

But I prefer the first way.

Comment: i accept your answer; i will go with videos list call; you can pass a max of fifty video ids but thats fine....will have to make some requests :) thx